# pymel how to get right type of selected node

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm starting exploring python in maya (pymel) and I have a problem with getting right type of selected object.

In outliner I have selected camera but when I'm executing code below it's returning type "transform". How to get right type ("camera")?

```
from pymel.core import *

selection = ls(sl=True)

print(selection[0].nodeType())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera construct is a combination of a transform node and a shape node. You selected the transform node so the output is correct. Either select the shape node below (make shapes visible in the outliner display menu) or simply do a selection[0].getShape().

Comment: yep it works thanks, `selection[0].getShape().nodeType()` just returns "camera"

Comment: if your script is specificly looking for camera, you can selection = ls(sl=True, type='camera') and then use cam[0].getTransform() if you need to manipulate the transform